# How to add a TLS listener to a network load balancer in AWS

Tags: amazon-elb

I'm attempting to add a TLS listener to a network load balancer. From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-elbv2-listener this shouldn't be possible, since the `SSLCertificateArns` and `SSLPolicy` params note "This option is only applicable to environments with an Application Load Balancer".

This is the policy (some details masked XXX):

```
option_settings:
  aws:elbv2:listener:443:
    DefaultProcess: default
    ListenerEnabled: 'true'
    Protocol: TCP
    SSLCertificateArns: arn:aws:acm:XXX
    SSLPolicy: ELBSecurityPolicy-XXX
```

Sure, fine, I get `Failed Environment update activity. Reason: Configuration validation exception: Invalid option value: 'null' (Namespace: 'aws:elbv2:listener:443', OptionName: 'SSLCertificateArns'): SSL options are not supported for Network Load Balancers.` when I do this. Other AWS docs support this position, e.g. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-nlb.html#environments-cfg-nlb-intro.

However - I *can* add a TLS listener and specify the security policy and certificate via the AWS console. I also tried `Protocol: TLS` in `option_settings`, which is what I can use in the AWS console, but I get error `Failed Environment update activity. Reason: Configuration validation exception: Invalid option value: 'TLS' (Namespace: 'aws:elbv2:listener:443', OptionName: 'Protocol'): Only TCP Protocols are supported for Network Load Balancers .`. Is this simply something that the AWS console does and can't be set via `option_settings`, or am I misunderstanding something important?